# Можно ли говорить о развитии русского языка?

Tags: общие-вопросы, недопустимая-метка

Что вообще подразумевается под развитием языка? И как отличить его от деградации (которую, по моему убеждению, мы наблюдаем сейчас)?
И, если таковое все-таки имеет место в настоящее время, то в чем оно выражается? Как изменился язык по сравнению, например, с серединой ХХ века?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да уж, действительно, что мы понимаем под "развитием" языка? Развитие как прогресс - движение к чему-то  устроенному более сложно? Тогда язык действительно деградирует, потому что он стремится к упрощению.Но плохо это или хорошо?
Грамматика др-русского языка была заметно сложнее, чем грамматика церковно-славянского языка.Это развитие или деградация? Весьма противоречивый вопрос. Ученый Михаил Эпштейн недавно посчитал количество слов в словарях и сделал вывод, что лексика намного уменьшилась, деградировала количественно.Другие говорят о качественной деградации: литературный язык вобрал в себя речь субкультур. Язык меняется, это понятно, но в худшую или в лучшую стороны?Давайте проанализируем изменения в словарном составе:
 1) происходит интенсивное образование новых слов по старым моделям XIX – XX вв. и по моделям, ставшим продуктивными в XX в.(с суффиксами -ирова -изирова-; сложением двух основ ;начиная с конца 20-х гг. появляются составные слова, активизировалась аббревиация); 2) словарный состав русского языка пополняется иноязычной лексикой,происходит адаптация заимствований, на их базе создаются новые русские слова; 3) в связи с процессом демократизации литературного языка лексика и фразеология внелитературная: просторечная, диалектная, профессиональная, жаргонная — входит в состав нормативной лексики и фразеологии; 4) меняется семантика под влиянием внутриязыковых процессов и экстралингвистических факторов ; 5) уходит из языка старая лексика, называющая понятия, связанные со старым укладом жизни,-советизмы .Все эти явления имеют свои плюсы и свои минусы. Лучше или хуже стал язык функционировать? А вот это смотря как мы им пользуемся. Может, не язык, а общество, им пользующееся, деградирует? Тоже спорно. Мы все разные. Так что язык живёт, развивается, в смысле меняется, как сама жизнь.

Я думаю, нельзя вообще говорить об улучшении или ухудшении языка - просто об изменении.

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, к деградации языка можно отнести только его вымирание. Все остальные явления его обогащают. Русский язык явно ещё не собирается уходить на покой, следовательно,  он развивается. Развитие — это, например, заимствование слов из других языков для облегчения общения или для обозначение новых (и не очень) предметов и явлений, также развитие — это изменение языка под влиянием, как говорит большинство.  
Не понимаю, где вы увидали деградацию русского. Возможно, вам не нравятся новые словечки. Ну,  тогда  вместо *"фейсбук"* говорите *"мордакнига"*, вместо *"интерфейс"* — *"междумордие"*, *"интернет"* — *"всемирная компьютерная сеть"*. Возможно, вам кажется, что вокруг полно безграмотных, поэтому язык ухудшается. Во-первых, в начале прошлого века всего пара человек на деревню умели читать и писать. Во-вторых, если все безграмотные начнут говорить не так, как написано в словаре, то словарь изменится, и в итоге все грамотные станут говорить так же, как и все неграмотные. Так что скоро можно будет говорить *"звОнишь"* и не стыдиться.  
Язык за полвека успел поменяться. Например, полвека назад не было никакого интернета, никакого дабстепа, никаких слайдеров и так далее. Нам эти слова абсолютно понятны, они вошли в язык. Основные же правила (пунктуация, например) законодательно не менялись с 1956 года.

Comment: >  не менялись, кажется, с 1954 года

с 56-го

В остальном согласна.



Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что говоря о развитии кто-то противопоставляет его именно деградации. 
Нормально развитие противопоставляется застою.
А вообще - надо смотреть контекст. Может так случиться, что автор под развитием как раз деградацию и имеет в виду.

Answer (score 0):

Развитие языка - это [перемены](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F) в языке. В этом смысле язык развивается, а [гумбольдтовская](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D1%82,_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC) теория "эволюции языковых типологий" не вполне состоятельна (то есть даже типологически языки развиваются не от "простого к сложному", а от одних преобладающих "[правил](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80) [игры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)" к другим (новым).

По сравнению с серединой ХХ столетия можно заметить:

- меньшее использование аббревиатур и сокращенно-составных слов;
- сокращение (редкость) диалектных форм;
- появление социолектов вместо диалектов;
- рост количества англицизмов;
- для религиозной лексики, основанной на восточных языках (связано в том числе и с исламской конфессией) - рост числа заимствованных существительных при почти полном отсутствии заимствований в части глаголов;
- сглаживание границы между официальным и повседневным стилями коммуникации;
- сдвиг (большая вариативность или откровенное пренебрежение) ударениями;
- перемены в статусе табуированной лексики;
- исчезновение универсальных форм вежливого обращения (не то чтобы "гражданин", "гражданка" и "товарищ" были особенно вежливыми - не говоря о формах "мужчина" и "женщина", но всё же...);
- появление новых междомтий и эмотиконов.